# how to show already existed permission using checked checkbox in Edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

i have to show a list of permissions attached to role. while creating the role which permissions are attached to that role using checkbox should be displayed checked in edit page. for this i have created a viewmodel. when i call the edit page all the checkboxes for permissions of permission table are in checked mode. i have three table role,permission and roledetail the checked permissions are coming from roledetail table. please help where i am doing wrong.
my tables are as follows 
Role

```
RoleId int,
RoleName varchar(25),
[Description] varchar(100),
Deleted bit
```

Permission

```
PermissionId int,
PermissionName varchar(25)
```

RoleDeatil

```
RoleDetailId int,
RoleId int,
PermissionId int
AddedOn datetime
```

here is my view Model

```
public class PermissionVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RoleEdit(int id, ViewModelRole viewModelRole)
        {
            Role role = roleService.GetRole(id);
            viewModelRole.Role = role;
            PopulateAssignedPermissionData(role);
            if (role == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(viewModelRole);
        }
        private void PopulateAssignedPermissionData(Role role)
        {
            var allPermission = tDbContext.Permissions;
            var rolePermissions = new HashSet<int>(tDbContext.Permissions.Select(p => p.PermissionId));
            var viewModel = new List<PermissionVM>();
            foreach (var permission in allPermission)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new PermissionVM
                {
                    ID = permission.PermissionId,
                    Name = permission.PermissionName,
                    IsSelected = rolePermissions.Contains(permission.PermissionId)
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Permissions = viewModel;
        }
```

View

```
@model light.ViewModels.ViewModelRole
 @{
         List<light.ViewModels.PermissionVM> permissions = ViewBag.Permissions;
          foreach (var permission in permissions)
          {
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
               <input type="checkbox" 
                      name="tags" 
                      class="no-margin"
                      id="=ids" value="@permission.ID" 
                      @(Html.Raw(permission.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                       @permission.Name
                </div>
              </div>
          }
       }
```

Note= in creation time when role is creating the RoleId and attached PermissionId's  are storing in Roledetail Table and i have to show all permission in my page but ony those checkboxes should be checked which are present in roledetail table. please help.. i am stuck for hours.

Comment: Your view makes no sense in relation to the view model. It will not post back correctly. In fact there is no point having a view model if your going to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for Edit Controller , and rests are Fine

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RoleEdit(int id, ViewModelRole viewModelRole)
        {
            viewModelRole.Role = roleService.GetRole(id);
            var allPermission = tDbContext.Permissions;
            var rolePermissions = (from p in preFlightDbContext.Permissions
                                   join rd in tDbContext.RoleDetails on p.PermissionId equals rd.PermissionId
                                   where rd.RoleId == id
                                   select p.PermissionId).Distinct();
            var viewModel = new List<PermissionVM>();
            foreach (var permission in allPermission)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new PermissionVM
                {
                    ID = permission.PermissionId,
                    Name = permission.PermissionName,
                    IsSelected = rolePermissions.Contains(permission.PermissionId)
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Permissions = viewModel;
            return View(viewModelRole);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your permission should be filtered by the role. Something like this :

```
var rolePermissions = new HashSet<int>(tDbContext.RoleDetail.Where(rd => rd.RoleId == role.RoleID).Select(rd => rd.PermissionId));
```

Your passing the role to your function but don't even use it : PopulateAssignedPermissionData(Role role). If i understand properly the code, now the `allPermission` and the `rolePermissions` are the same.

Comment: nice sir @Mathieu Labrie Parent

Comment: Thank you so much thats the thing i missed